# KSH history weirdness

Tags: ksh, command-history

I'm running KSH on RHEL 2.6 on x86.  KSH version is:

sh (AT&T Research) 93u+ 2012-08-01

Switching to Bash or back to Tcsh (which I happily used at my old job) is not possible.

The first annoying thing I noticed about KSH is that sometimes my history from different terminals (I have many terminals open at a time) got mixed together when scrolling through history with the up key.  I then learned that there's a single HISTFILE shared by all my terminals.  Fine, but still weird that they weren't always getting intermixed.  I also noticed the HISTFILE wasn't always updated immediately.  Eventually I decided that KSH was probably buffering some command history and periodically flushing the contents to HISTFILE.  I couldn't find that behavior documented anywhere but it seems like a reasonable explanation.

I really want different history for each session, so I added this to my .kshrc file:

HISTFILE=~/.hist.$(tty | sed 's;.*/;;')

which is supposed to give a unique HISTFILE per terminal.  It does that, which is great.  But...these HISTFILES seem to periodically get cleared.  Most of mine have a file size of 0 bytes right now.

**Update:**  The individual HISTFILEs for all my open terminals are being cleared every 10 minutes.  Like clockwork.

Anybody seen this before???

**Update:** Two years later and I am still no closer to an answer.  It's been particularly annoying lately.  Started poking around the ksh source but I'm a hardware designer and there aren't a lot of comments so this is pretty tough.

Well maybe this is a clue.  Every line in my history files starts with a ^@ character (as rendered by emacs).  I think that means 0x40 (@ character) + 0x80 (for the control bit) = 0xc0 = octal 300.  The only special characters mentioned in history.c, as far as I can tell, are 0201 and 0202.  My history files do start with \201 (again, as rendered by emacs, I guess this is octal).

Here's a sample of a typical history file, does this seem normal:

```
�ls
 pwd
  clear
  ls
 ls
 tty
```

Hmm those control characters don't display correctly.  Transcribed as regular characters it looks like:

```
\201^Als
^@pwd
^@^@clear
^@^@ls
^@ls
^@tty
^@^@
```

Sometimes I get two of those ^@ characters and sometimes one, and I can't figure out why.  This might not be a clue but I have no other leads right now.

**UPDATE:**  SOLVED!  Well almost.  No sooner did I post that then I started searching for some other things in history.c.  I saw this:

```c
/*
 * clean out history file OK if not modified in HIST_RECENT seconds
 */
static int hist_clean(int fd)
{
    struct stat statb;
    return(fstat(fd,&statb)>=0 && (time((time_t*)0)-statb.st_mtime) >= HIST_RECENT);
}
```

and no surprise here, HIST_RECENT is set to 600, exactly the 10 minute interval I was looking for.  I haven't quite figured out how to disable this yet, but it sure seems like intentional behavior, no matter how much I hate it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `ksh93` writes its command line history to file as you go, while `bash` writes it when the shell exits.  Digging though [some source code](https://opensource.apple.com/source/ksh/ksh-13/ksh/src/cmd/ksh93/edit/history.c.auto.html), it seems that the in-memory history buffer is 4k (`HIST_BSIZE` in the code), but I'm not able to figure out whether it flushes this when it's full or after a certain number of commands (whan may `HIST_MARKSZ` be doing in this code?).

And yes, many interactive sessions share history if they use the same `HISTFILE` setting.  This is documented (my emphasis):

> Command Re-entry.
>
> The text of the last `HISTSIZE` (default 512) commands entered from a
>          terminal device is saved in a history file.  The file `$HOME/.sh_history`
>          is used if the `HISTFILE` variable is not set or if the file it names is
>          not writable.  **A shell can access the commands of all interactive
>          shells which use the same named `HISTFILE`.**

The history file will be kept to the size specified in `HISTSIZE` but it will not be truncated periodically as you experience.  What's happening for you is, I *think*, that since you use `tty` to set a unique `HISTFILE` for each interactive shell session, exiting and restarting interactive sessions may or may not pick up the "correct" history file depending on what TTY the shell is connected to.

If a new TTY (never used with a session before) is allocated for a shell session, it's history file will naturally be empty.

Comment: Nah, it has nothing to do with exiting or restarting sessions.  The history files get cleared every 10 minutes, no matter what.

Comment: @Matt I can't reproduce that with the same version of the shell unless I have some cron process or similar to clear out the history file.

Comment: Yeah I've been wondering if there's something going on in the background.  No idea what else could be causing this.  Thanks.

Comment: I'm trying an experiment where the history file doesn't have the leading dot.  I could imagine some other tool that produces .hist files for some reason, and it clearing things out.  We'll know in 10 minutes...

Comment: Without the leading dot, the files still seem to get touched every 10 minutes (timestamp updates) but the contents are preserved.  Will keep an eye on it over the next few days....